# Magento 2 - RabbitMQ Message has been rejected: Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet

Tags: magento2, message-queue, rabbit-mq

I'm using RabbitMQ as message broker as publisher/subscriber, but sometimes I receive the following error:

> Message has been rejected: Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=5987 in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228

I think that this occure because the connection with MySQL stays open and when exceed `wait_timeout = 500` from `my.cnf` the next message cause me this error. Now, how can I avoid this? Is there a way to close connection from my consumers?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Running into the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This post "[Symfony2 and RabbitMQ: lessons learned](https://blog.vandenbrand.org/2015/01/09/symfony2-and-rabbitmq-lessons-learned/)" does a nice job of explaining the problem (replace Symfony with Magento and it's still valid);

> Because the consumer is one process that keeps running, that also
>   means that the service container and stuff keeps existing in memory.
>   When you’ve done some queries the database connection keeps open in
>   the background. And if it’s quiet on our queue, it may take some time
>   before we reach the message limit. If that time exceeds the
>   connect_timeout of your MySQL server, you’ll run into the warnings and
>   errors about lost connections.
>
> Of course we should close the connection after the message is
>   processed or could try catch for Doctrine DBAL connection exceptions
>   or increase the connect_timeout setting but thats just denying the
>   real problem. Running consumers with a booted Symfony2 kernel just
>   doesn’t work so well.

So in short; when the queue isn't (very) busy, the MySQL connection stays open for a longer period thereby exceeding MySQL's timeout. When the queue is busy however, it'll hit the message limit for one connection and create a new connection, avoiding the timeout.

Two short term options; 
1. Raise the MySQL timeout (but to what? that depends on how 'busy' your system is).
2. Lower the message limit per connection. I'm not sure how to do this.

I don't know about a long-term solution where we can both tailor the not-so-busy moments and the busy moments and avoid the time-out altogether without sacrificing performance in busy moments.

Edit; after re-reading your initial post and understanding the issue better, I now see you already realized exactly this.